# How do we deduce the Jacquet-Langlands correspondence from Fargues' two towers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, langlands-conjectures

In trying to understand the geometric proof of the local-Langlands and Jacquet-Langlands correspondence which uses Fargues's two tower theorem, I am having trouble finding a nice source on this, and I would deeply appreciate some enlightenment on one of the last steps. Let's focus on the Jacquet-Langlands correspondence (i.e., leaving out the Galois group from the story for simplicity).

My very rough understanding so far is as follows. Let $LT$ be Lubin-Tate space of height $h$ up to quasi-isogeny, and $LT^n$ denote added level $n$ structure. The limit over level $n$ structures, $LT^\infty$, is a $GL_h(\mathbb{Z}_p)$-torsor over $LT$, and there is an action of $O_{D^\times}$ from precomposing the reduction isomorphism with an automorphism of the height $h$ formal group. Here, $D^\times$ is the units of a division algebra with height $1/h$.

Similarly, let $\Omega$ denote Drinfel'd projective space, and $\Omega^n$ denote added level $n$ structure. We again take a limit of the tower and get $\Omega^\infty$, however now, $\Omega^\infty$ is a $D^\times$-torsor over $\Omega$, and there is a $GL_h(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ action on each level.

Fargue's two tower theorem gives us that $LT^\infty$ and $\Omega^\infty$ are $(GL_h(\mathbb{Z}_p) \times O_{D^\times})$-equivariantly isomorphic. Thus, we may take their $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$ etale cohomologies where $p \neq \ell$, and they are isomorphic as $(GL_h(\mathbb{Z}_p) \times O_{D^\times})$-representations. We may then present these representations as: $\prod \tau \otimes \sigma$, where $\tau$ and $\sigma$ only show up in a pair if they are dual under the Jacquet-Langlands correspondence.

**Here's my question:** Why do pairs $\tau \otimes \sigma$ only show up if $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are Jacquet-Langlands dual representations?

It seems this somehow comes from the fact that the $GL_h(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and $O_{D^\times}$ "switch roles" in the two towers, but I would love to understand this in detail.